# Why findAnnotation or getAnnotation returns null?

Tags: java, spring-3

I'm writing some aop code with sping3.
Here is my annotation.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface DataSource {
    String name() default "foo"
}
```

And I set a `pointcut` to the above annotation.

```
<aop:pointcut id="service" expression="@annotation(com.foo.datasource.DataSource)" />
<aop:advisor advice-ref="dataSourceExchange" pointcut-ref="service" order="1"/>
<bean id="dataSourceExchange" class="com.foo.datasource.DataSourceExchange"/>
```

I write a service method and add the above annotation to it. In the `DataSourceExchange` class, which will be called before the service, I try to get the annotation.

```
class DataSourceExchange implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Method name : "
                + invocation.getMethod().getName());
        System.out.println("Method arguments : "
                + Arrays.toString(invocation.getArguments()));

        DataSource dataSource = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(invocation.getMethod(), DataSource.class);
        System.out.println(dataSource);
```

I get the method's name correctly.
But the annotation `dataSource` just returns `null`.
What's the problem? I think the service method I called is definitely be annotation-ed, otherwise it won't trigger the `pointcut`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the question by using 
`Method realMethod = invocation.getThis().getClass().getDeclaredMethod(proxyedMethod.getName(), proxyedMethod.getParameterTypes())`; to find out the real method.

For more details, check [Alter dataSource in Spring By AOP And Annotation](http://kamushin.github.io/debug/aop_proxy.html)